# Technology behind Google World Wide Maze

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Does anybody know which mix of technologies are behind [Google World Wide Maze](http://chrome.com/maze/) experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It utilizes [Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for a synchronized client-server-client connection. Server-side thay use node.js to handle TCP connections.

3D graphics are rendered by [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) with the help of many popular javascript libraries, such as - three.js, Create.js and Require.js.

The only thing I'm not sure of is, how they ported an app to Android. However, I firmly believe that they would have compiled already written Javascript, rather than rewriting everything in Java.

Comment: ported an app to Android? how do you mean, from what I see, nothing is ported, they using chrome on both sides(pc and android or ios)

Comment: From a moment I saw that it can communicate with hardware API, I thought it was a native app. Sorry, my bad.
But, this way or another, whether it's a native app or web app running on web-kit, it still communicates with other client throughout web-sockets.

Answer (score 1):

The [page](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/world-wide-maze/?f=) on it at ChromeExperiments.com indicates it's using [WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webgl/info).

An article [here](http://creativejs.com/2013/03/chrome-world-wide-maze/) indicates it's also using the CreateJS tools and RequireJS.

Comment: ok, so for rendering webgl, but I'm more interested in sync part-how it manages to sync mobile and pc chrome realtime?

Comment: They're showing off the fact that Chrome Tab Sync [works across devices](http://www.gizmag.com/chrome-tab-sync/22602/) now :)